# How to make ScrollView includes WebView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, uikit

I want to make a View in ScrollView includes WKWebView like Gmail.
Gmail's body view(webview) to read mail is below.
The WebView can zoom in/out but, top-area(subject, sender...etc) does not zoom.
If I scroll vertically, it will be scrolled with top-area and WebView together.
I am sorry for no good english skill.

[image]

```
struct TopInfoViewModel {
    let subject: String
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let date: String
}

private struct RootView: View {
    let viewModel: TopInfoViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            TopInfoView(viewModel: viewModel)
                .border(.blue)
            
            Color.gray
                .frame(height: 1)
            
            BodyView()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}

struct TopInfoView: View {
    @State private var isOpenedReceiverView: Bool = true
    let viewModel: TopInfoViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            // 제목
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(viewModel.subject)
                    .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold))
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
            
            // Sender
            SenderInfoView(isOpened: $isOpenedReceiverView,
                           name: viewModel.name,
                           email: viewModel.email)
            
            // 날짜, 글자크기 변경, 중요표시
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                // 날짜
                Text(viewModel.date)
                    .font(.system(size: 13))
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 20)
    }
}

private struct SenderInfoView: View {
    @Binding var isOpened: Bool
    
    let name: String
    let email: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Button {
                print("from label touched")
            } label: {
                HStack(spacing: 2) {
                    Text("from")
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                        .frame(width: 52, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 4)
            
            // name button
            Button {
                print("name touched = \(email)")
            } label: {
                Text(name)
                    .lineLimit(1)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WebViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    @State var isLoadedWebView: Bool = false
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some WKWebView {
        /// 자바스크립트 파일을 불러와 UserContentController에 추가
        /// - Parameters:
        ///   - fileName: 추가할 자바스크립트 파일명. 확장자 제외
        func importJavaScript(fileName: String, userContentController: inout WKUserContentController) {
            if let scriptPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "js"),
               let scriptSource = try? String(contentsOfFile: scriptPath) {
                let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
                
                userContentController.addUserScript(script)
            }
        }
        
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        var userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        
        config.processPool = WKProcessPool()
        config.dataDetectorTypes = .all
        config.websiteDataStore = .nonPersistent()
        userContentController.add(ContentController(), name: "eventNameTest")
        
        // load javascript
        importJavaScript(fileName: "script", userContentController: &userContentController)
        config.userContentController = userContentController
        
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        webView.isOpaque = false
        webView.backgroundColor = .blue
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.scrollView.decelerationRate = .normal
        webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.backgroundColor = .white
        webView.load(request)
        
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: some WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> WebViewCoordinator {
        WebViewCoordinator(self)
    }
    
    class WebViewCoordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var webViewWrapper: WebViewWrapper
        
        init(_ webView: WebViewWrapper) {
            self.webViewWrapper = webView
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            webViewWrapper.isLoadedWebView = true
        }
    }
    
    class ContentController: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        }
    }
}

struct BodyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        WebViewWrapper()
            .background(.yellow)
            .border(.red)
    }
}

struct RootView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RootView(viewModel: TopInfoViewModel(subject: "subject1", name: "name1", email: "email1", date: "date1"))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far? and what issues you are getting?

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: @FahimParkar I added my codes. A below image is a Preview image of sample code

Comment: @MatBuompy I added my codes

Comment: @strawnut I don't get what your exact problem is. You want the web view to be able to be scrolled?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted the view to be scrollable, I don't understand very well your request, sorry. Anyway, what I did was to wrap the content of the body of your `RootView` in a `GeometryReader` and used its **size** property to give the WebView, named `BodyView` in this case some witdth and height. Then I also wrapped it in a `ScrollView`:

```
private struct RootView: View {
    let viewModel: TopInfoViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let size = proxy.size
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    TopInfoView(viewModel: viewModel)
                        .border(.blue)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                    Color.gray
                        .frame(height: 1)
                    
                    BodyView()
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Also, I changed this line to true too:

```
webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

I don't exactly know how it is supposed to be set but, if you set it to **false** the rest View will scroll as if it was an image and you can still zoom in/out in the WebView anyway.
Let me know if this is what you meant.